# How to ChunkOutput using Jersey 1?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I'm trying to figure out how to chunk the output of a servlet response using jersey 1.x. There are many working examples for Jersey 2.x using org.glassfish.jersey.server.ChunkedOutput.

I cant seem to find an example for jersey 1x.

Can anyone provide a pointer to an example for chunked output with Jersey 1.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey 1.x does not support non-blocking IO and chunked output.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I was concerned that was the case. I'm hoping someone knows for sure..

Comment: I know for sure NIO is not supported in Jersey 1.x (Jersey 2 had to go through a significant refactoring to support that). If you don't mind blocking IO, you can return InputStream from your resource method and make the data available to it in chunks.

Comment: I realized, returning StreamingOutput would be even easier to implement: https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html

Comment: I was just looking at it.. but need to first get some sleep :)